# How to drag and drop an item on top another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a little game, and have a problem with the dragging and dropping of objects : I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer on two buttons. What I want is for button 2 to be highlighted when button 1 and button 2 overlap. I assume it should happen in UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, so I wrote it this way :

```
//This code to make button1 move
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

//This code to handle what happens when button 1 is dragged around
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //And this code to handle what happens when button1 and button2 overlap
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([button2 frame], translation)) {
        button2.highlighted = YES;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to come from the if (CGRectContainsPoint([button2 frame], translation)) statement. Anyone can help?